# Mapping a field from a view to my model using Entity Framework and setting it as read only

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework code-first (non auto generated) and I am trying to map some properties in my `OnModelCreating` event. Most properties are from a SQL Server table however there is a field I want to include in my model from a view, I have done this and set it as `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`.

However EF tries to update the view, how do I tell EF to not update my view and treat it as read only, the error I get is...

> Cannot update the view or function 'VIEWNAME' because it contains
>   aggregates, or a DISTINCT or GROUP BY clause, or PIVOT or UNPIVOT
>   operator

I can see plenty of things to make your view update-able but no to just treat it as read only

**UPDATE**

After trying a few things I have added `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to the property when defining it in my model and this seems to have done the trick, seems a bit strange though as setting it as Identity doesn't make much sense to me over setting it as computed but seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this on your properties?

`public virtual string MyProperty { get; internal set; }`

this way the entity consumer cannot change it.

Comment: No I hadn't I will try it now and post feedback, thanks for the response

Comment: Just tried it now and and it seems to have got rid of the original error but now is coming up with 'Update or insert of view or function 'VIEWNAME' failed because it contains a derived or constant field'

Comment: I have updated my original post with something that seems to have fixed it although it seems strange to me how this has fixed it.